# SQL ALL without a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am looking for a way to replicate this code without using a subquery.

```
Case
    When 'White' = All(Table1.Color1,
    Table1.Color2, Table2.Color1,
    Table2.Color2) Then 1 Else 0 End As allWhite
```

This seems like a very convient way of doing it but I receive a wrong syntax error:
`Wrong syntax near 'Table1'` (translated so maybe not 100% accurate)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: and the syntax error is??? the full query with sample values and desired output might be useful too.

Comment: edited it in but it's the generic one

Comment: I believe the values in `ALL` have to be specified using a subquery, and it can only contain 1 column so this won't fit your needs I guess.

Comment: Why no subquery? Sql is _good_ at subqueries.

Comment: A subquery would really prolong the code because it would require an extra 10-12 lines of code for this query.

Comment: You could look into creating a user defined function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
CASE 
    WHEN  
        Table1.Color1 = 'White' AND
        Table1.Color2 = 'White' AND
        Table2.Color1 = 'White' AND
        Table2.Color2 = 'White'
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END AS AllWhite
```

Comment: Yeah that's the standard way of doing it and it works, but it's more complex. Given that the ALL operator exists, I am wondering why it only allows subqueries and not straight columns.

Comment: @Spurious . . . I would rather the syntax supported `t1.Color1 = t2.Color2 = t1.Color2 = t2.Color2 = 'White'`, but it doesn't.  That is the way that SQL is defined.  If you want Microsoft to add an extension for SQL Server, you can lobby them, but I wouldn't have much hope of convincing many other people of the need.

Comment: Honestly that exact syntax was my first try but it obviously did not work, I then tried ALL and it did not work either. I can understand why the first syntax is not necessarily supported but ALL has everything that is needed.